# Tips on creating "frozen bodypart ripped apart"

Tags: sound-design

Hi! My first question here!

I was wondering if anybody has any good tips for creating frozen bodyparts that gets ripped apart?

Example:
A man's hand gets frozen so badly that it's practically ice and another man shakes his hand, the hand gets stuck on the frozen mans hand and the other man tries to get his hand out and ends up ripping the frozen man's hand with him! (Maybe not the best example but it involves what I'm looking for)

Comment: I would also reference 127 hours. Per the reviews, several people fainted in the theater - if that's the effect you want to create.

Answer (score 6):

Soak paper towels and freeze them, then pull them apart -- individually, and in stacks -- until it stops sounding good (this may happen immediately.)

Add some gooey wet noodles or tearing fruit sounds, as well.

Comment: @Dave - nice disclaimer. lol!

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't tried it, but I think it would sound fine... then again, I may be remembering a sound that was designed instead of something that actually happened to me.

Answer (score 4):

buy chicken, put in freezer, wait a few hours, take out, press record... there's a starting point?

Comment: you'd have to take it out before it truly freezes.  fully Frozen chicken is like a rock.

Answer (score 3):

+1 above..

Maybe also try something with Cauliflower or cabbage too? Try cutting about 1/3 the way through and then get your fingers in to rip it apart in one quick motion. Try freezing that for a while first too.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a perfect excuse for some dry ice experiments, buy a chilli bin full

Comment: Be careful not to burn yourself, though. Throw a metal necklace or chain into a bin full of dry ice sometime - sounds awesome!!!

Answer (score 3):

Layer a rip of velcro, paper, cardboard and cloth in sync so that it sounds like a single source, pitch shift down the cardboard and then add a layered bone crack (celery, carrot or chicken) to taste.

Comment: @Iain, I love how this sounds like a soup recipe. lol

Comment: That's essentially what sound design is, @Syndicate ;) It's best done with home-grown recordings and not bland store-bought ones that have been freezer-stored on 44.1 16 CDs - fresh 192K 24 bit recordings picked from your garden are the best.

Comment: And I don't want none of those DMRs (Dynamically Modified Recordings) in my food, either.

Comment: @Utopia - You're preaching to the choir. I was just saying that hearing it put that way makes me happy.

Answer (score 3):

I've used King Crab legs for this very thing. The bigger the better. They are a good combination of crunch from the shell and flesh rip from the meat inside. Put on a pair of leather gloves and start ripping.

Answer (score 2):

- Contact Mic (and regular) recordings of packing tape being peeled off of glass (commonly used for creating lightning ripples).
- Also tearing a cardboard box slowly might work as well.
- Crumbling cellophane slowly. *Both hard and soft cellophane ie: cigarette wrapper vs saran wrap

Those might do the trick or at least be a nice thing to layer in. Maybe a bit of choice timestretching and other types of post processing, especially some careful eq filtering to give the sound motion. I've used all the above sounds once when I wanted sort of a glacier splitting type sound.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the tape on glass thing.  Even if I don't use it, I'm gonna try that tonight.

Answer (score 2):

Freezer-burned meat is great for this. It tears more easily, makes more sound, but still sounds like meat. A thin piece of cheap chuck steak should sound work nicely. You can get a bunch of takes from one good size steak, then layer them up and mix and match them together for more sounds/body parts. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd get a snowcone or shave-ice (fine shave ice, not the crushed ice from the refrige) and play around with it as a sweetener to the great suggestions above.

The specific sound I'm thinking of is when you bite off a popsicle and that shaven, bristling, splintering sound of ice you hear in your mouth - this could be a good detail to add in.

It's all about details.

P.S. If you don't have access to shave ice, freezing a watermelon may work, or freezing a 1-liter bottle of soda (coke, pepsi, etc.)

Above all, take proper precaution not to get all of our great messy frozen suggestions on the microphone!